# Problems from finite fields theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

The problem is to find two distinct polynomials over $F_p$ which coincide as functions $F_p \to F_p$. So far I don't know where to begin.
And the second question how one can check whether given polynomial $f(x) \in Q[x]$ is irreducible? (maybe it's matter: all coefficients is in $Z$) I know only sufficient condition.

Comment: These are two pretty much completely unrelated questions, but the second one is probably too broad anyway. For the first one: Do you know Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Not exactly, but I always can find it via google.

Answer (score 1):

For any field $\;\Bbb F_p=\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}\pmod p\;$ , the non-trivial polynomial of degree $\;p\;$

$$f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-(p-1))$$

is **the same, as a function** $\;:\Bbb F_p\to\Bbb F_p\;$, as the zero *polynomial* $\;g(x)\in\Bbb F_p[x],\;\;g(x)\equiv 0\;$ , of degree $\;-1\;$ (or $\;-\infty\;$ , depending on the use).

The second question has no definite answer *in the general case*: for polynomials of degree $\;\le3\;$ though, a polynomial is irreducible over *any* field $\;\Bbb F\;$ iff it has no root there, and there are some other rather restricted criteria for very specific cases.